# Printing in for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a for loop that goes from 1 to 1000. I want to only print the 8th, 16th, and 64th solution of the problem in the loop. How do i do that? I'm brand new to matlab so if you help may you be as simple as possible.

Comment: My friend, you need to sit back and learn how to program. Find a tutorial or something.

Comment: That is clearly why i'm here, to learn from people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a big improvement but you can do this too.

```
for  ii=1:1000
      if ii==8 || ii==16 || ii==64
             //print solution
      end 
end
```

Comment: Or use `if ismember(ii, [8 16 64])`. Then the list can be extended in a simple way.

Comment: Thanks, it is a nicer and useful way that i didnt know

Answer (score 0):

if you are only looking for the 8th, 16th, and 64, just put if statements in your for loop.

```
for k=1:1000
    if k == 8
        solution on the 8th run    
    elseif k == 16
        solution on the 16th run    
    else if k == 64
        solution on the 64th run
    else
        solution for all other runs (leave out if not needed)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a real question?

```
for ii=1:1000
   if ii=8
       //print here
   end
   if ii=16
       //print here
   end
end
```